# How to convert an input string into an array which contains each character of that string - ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, loops

Hi I have to convert a string which is input in an unrelated method, into an array where each of it's characters is an element. I then need to iterate through this array printing each odd character. I am mainly having issues putting this string into an array, I am writing in Ruby. Any help would be amazing please. Thanks you.

Comment: Something like `input = gets.chomp.split`

Comment: Please include an example of input and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `chars` to get an array of all characters of a given string, for example:

```
input = "string"

input.chars
#=> ["s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"]
```

Answer (score 1):

To print each odd character you can split the string on every character then test if the index is odd like this:

```
def unrelated_method(input_string)
  input_string.split('').each_with_index do |char, index|
    puts char if index.odd?
  end
end
```

Another option is to loop through each character and keep track fo the index yourself, like this:

```
def unrelated_method(input_string)
  index = 0
  input_string.each_char do |char|
    puts char if index.odd?
    index += 1
  end
end
```

And you could, of course, short it down to this:

```
def unrelated_method(input_string)
  input_string.split('').each_with_index { |ca, i| puts ca if i.odd? }
end
```

Comment: You can avoid tracking `index` in option two using `with_index`:  `input_string.each_char.with_index { |char, index| puts char if index.odd? }`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
def print_odd_chars(str)
  str.each_char.each_with_index do |char, i|
    print char if i.odd?
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `#each_char` method which will give an enumerator so you can iterate over chars.

```
value = "Hello, World"
value.each_char { |char| puts char }
```